# how do I create a variable that points to a string with an object from another variable?

Tags: javascript, object

I apologize in advance if I worded the question wrong but I have this issue.

```
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
}
```

I am supposed to create a new variable that contains the address, city, state and zip but I am not to sure how to do that.

So far I've tried:

```
const fullAddress = address.city.state.zip
```

but I get an error saying that I have not defined the full address variable.
I am really not sure what to do next and I have re-watched the video about 5 times now and I am totally lost. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create several restaurant objects with dfferent addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
const fullAddress = `${restaurant.address}, ${restaurant.city}, ${restaurant.state}, ${restaurant.zipcode}`
```

Please notice that it's not creating a binding between an object and a built string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let fullAddress = restaurant.address+" " +restaurant.city+ " "+restaurant.state+ " " + restaurant.zipcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let fullAddress = restaurant.name + restaurant.address + restaurant.city + restaurant.state + restaurant.zipcode


// neater version
// 

let fullAddress = restaurant.name + ", " + restaurant.address + restaurant.city + ", " + restaurant.state + ", " + restaurant.zipcode
```

Answer (score 0):

First way:

```
let fullAddress = restaurant['address'] + ', '+ restaurant['city'] + ', '+  restaurant['state']+ ' '+restaurant['zipcode']
```

Second Way:

```
let fullAddress = restaurant.address +', '+ restaurant.city +', '+ restaurant.state +' '+ restaurant.zipcode;
```